# Node JS use more than one registered helper on a page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express-handlebars

I have this code on my node js server, its version 8.11.1.

```
app.get('/parenting',(req,res)=>{
  dbtools.getCategories().then((result)=>{
   res.render('parenting.hbs',{result});
  }).catch((err)=>{
   res.status(401).send(err);
  });
});
```

That is the express route.

```
hbs.registerHelper('categoriesList',(categoriesList)=>{

 //does stuff with categories from db 

});
```

On the page itself I am using

```
{{{categoriesList}}}
```

To render the helper result on the page. All of this works great for one hbs.helper. I cannot figure out the syntax to add another similar function. I basically need one function to get the categories from the database and display them from the list and a second to get tags from the database and display those in a different section of the page. I have no issues creating the two functions. My specific issue is using two registered helpers on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

This call

```
res.render('parenting.hbs',{categories:result,tags:'testTag'});
```

will pass the values I need into one array available to both functions. Registering the second function in a similar manner and making sure of my return value solved the issue.